# Question regarding distributions and prediction

Tags: self-study, distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

During my learning about distributions I came up with the following prediction algorithm.
Given a dataset, for example a plot of stock prices to time.

1. Select a range of values from the graph (for stock prices: the last `n` values)
2. Check if the CDF of values fits a continuous distribution CDF
3. If it does predict the future point based on the fitting distribution
4. Repeat from 1

My question is: do I properly understand the things I am talking about, as observed from my question?

Also, theorizing, how accurate would such a prediction method be?

Comment: Stock prices are non-stationary; they do not follow any distribution. Try do the same thing and take n to infinity.  It's the *return* of stock prices that have a stable distribution.